# How to find the find the div data element using Selenium web driver and Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

[image]

I need to select "Australia" from this list using Selenium web driver, Python. And I have tried XPath and CSS selector but could not properly locate the element.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[@data-v-9d5976ee='Australia']").click()
```

Please instruct how can i locate the element? what type of locator should be used here to select the value i want from the list

Comment: Austria or Australia? Make your choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **XPath**:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Austria"]')
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div["Austria"]')
```